# Как получить список ip всех принтеров в ЛВС на c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, ip, принтер

Есть ЛВС. Часть ip-адресов у принтеров статична, а часть выдаётся DHCP-сервером. Нужно получить список ip всех принтеров в сети. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря tCode наткнулся на [небольшой проект](https://github.com/vinifr/-ListNetworks). Программа опрашивает все устройства в диапазоне ip и получает список принтеров при помощи протокола SNMP.

Answer (score 1):

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018001/is-there-a-net-way-to-enumerate-all-available-network-printers)

```
private void btnGetPrinters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Use the ObjectQuery to get the list of configured printers
    System.Management.ObjectQuery oquery =
        new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mosearcher =
        new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery);

    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mosearcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        System.Management.PropertyDataCollection pdc = mo.Properties;
        foreach (System.Management.PropertyData pd in pdc)
        {
            if ((bool)mo["Network"])
            {
                cmbPrinters.Items.Add(mo[pd.Name]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,но данный способ позволяет получить только те принтеры, которые подключены к текущему компьютеру, но в сети есть и другие принтеры, в этом и заключается главная проблема с которой я столкнулся.